# NullPointerException when implementing linkedStack

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, stack

I'm getting a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at datastructuresPart2.LinkedStack.pop(LinkedStack.java:20)
    at tests.StackTest.main(StackTest.java:66)
```

when trying to implement a linked stack. Pretty much the same code works in a different project, so I'm not sure what's going on. I'll post all the relevant code. (I've successfully ran it as an array. But I need to use a linked list...)

```
package datastructuresPart2;

import datastructuresPart2.Node;

public class LinkedStack<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements Stack<E> {


    private Node<E> top = null;

    @Override
    public void push(E element) {
        top = new Node<E>(element, top);
        size++;     
    }

    @Override
    public E pop() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("empty stack");
        E element = top.data;
        top = top.next;
        size--;
        return element;
        }

    @Override
    public E top() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("empty stack");
        return top.data;
    }

    @Override 
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
        top = null;
    }

    public boolean contains(E element) {
        for (Node<E> current = top; current != null; current = current.next) 
            if (element.equals(current.data))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Returns a string representation for this collection.
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String buffer = "[";
            if (! isEmpty()) {
                buffer += top.data;
                for (Node<E> current = top.next; current != null; current = current.next)
                    buffer += ", " + current.data;
            }
            return buffer + "]";
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        LinkedStack<E> other = (LinkedStack<E>) obj;



        int count = 0;
        for (Node<E> trav = other.top; trav != null; trav = trav.next){

            if (top.getData().equals(trav.getData())) {
                count++;    
            }

            top = top.getNext();
        }

        if (count == size)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I also use:

```
/*
 * StackTest.java
 * This source file contains a class that tests the Stack interface and
 * implementation.
 */

package tests;

import datastructuresPart2.*;

public class StackTest {

    // Serves as the entry point for this application.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> stk = new LinkedStack<>();
        Stack<String> stk2 = new LinkedStack<>();


        System.out.println("After creating a new stack...");
        CollectionTest.print(stk);
        System.out.println();

        stk.push("cat");
        stk.push("dog");
        stk.push("tree");
        stk.push("house");
        stk.push("boat");
        stk.push("woman");
        stk.push("man");
        stk.push("car");
        stk.push("pool");
        stk.push("motorcycle");
        stk.push("mailbox");

        System.out.println("After adding some elements...");
        CollectionTest.print(stk);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("After creating a new stack2...");
        CollectionTest.print(stk2);
        System.out.println();

        stk2.push("cat");
        stk2.push("dog");
        stk2.push("tree");
        stk2.push("house");
        stk2.push("boat");
        stk2.push("woman");
        stk2.push("man");
        stk2.push("car");
        stk2.push("pool");
        stk2.push("motorcycle");
        stk2.push("mailbox");

        System.out.println("The top element is " + stk.top());
        System.out.println("Does it contains a man? " + stk.contains("man"));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Are the stacks equal? " + stk.equals(stk2));

//      System.out.println("Traversing the stack...");
//      for (String element : stk)
//          System.out.println(element);
//      System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Removing: " + stk.pop());
        System.out.println("Removing: " + stk.pop());

        System.out.println("After removing the top two elements...");
        CollectionTest.print(stk);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Are the stacks equal? " + stk.equals(stk2));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("The top element is " + stk.top());
        System.out.println("Does it contains a man? " + stk.contains("man"));
        System.out.println();

        stk.clear();
        System.out.println("After clearing the stack...");
        CollectionTest.print(stk);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Trying to get the top element...");
        try {
            System.out.println("The top element is " + stk.top());
        }
        catch (EmptyCollectionException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDITS:

Node.java

```
package datastructuresPart2;

public class Node<T> {

    T data;
    Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getData() { return data; }
    public void setData(T data) { this.data = data; }
    public Node<T> getNext() { return next; }
    public void setNext(Node<T> next) { this.next = next; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data + "--->" + next; //recursion implicita
    }



}
```

AbstractCollection.java

```
package datastructuresPart2;

public abstract class AbstractCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {

    protected int size = 0;

    @Override
    public int size() { return size; }

    @Override 
    public void clear() { size = 0; }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() { return (size == 0); }

    @Override public abstract boolean contains(E element);
    @Override public abstract String toString();
    @Override public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);



}
```

EDIT: And Collection.java ...might as well put the whole thing lol.

```
package datastructuresPart2;

public interface Collection<E> {

    int size();

    boolean isEmpty();

    boolean contains(E element);

    void clear();



}
```

Comment: Can you identify which lines the error is referring to?

Comment: "       System.out.println("Removing: " + stk.pop());
        System.out.println("Removing: " + stk.pop());
"

Basically when I pop.

Comment: Where is LinkedStack.size()?

Comment: what line is datastructuresPart2.LinkedStack.pop(LinkedStack.java:20).Might be an issue with copy and paste/

Comment: @Antimony maybe this can help: http://www.uprb.edu/profesor/ahuertas/Sici4036/Asignaciones/Asig04/BagClassDiagramNoIterator.png

Comment: @SamFisher83 that would be: "E element = top.data;"

Comment: You should also post the Node class.

Comment: Argh how can I post code here properly formatted?

Comment: Oh, you also need to post your `Abstractcollection` class. You're obviously not using the `java.util` version since you never import it and your code wouldn't compile anyway.

Comment: The reason why you are getting error is that top = null. Maybe you should check for that case?

Comment: Don't post code in the comments.  Edit the question and add it there.

Comment: did u try debugging in a debugger?

Comment: @Foolish I think he's using a custom class that happens to be called AbstractCollection. Otherwise, there's no way that code would compile.

Comment: @Antimony yes it is a custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is happening because your `equals()` implementation is modifying the state of your stack which is probably not what you want.  You call `equals()` prior to the `pop()` line that is failing.

Here:

```
for (Node<E> trav = other.top; trav != null; trav = trav.next){

    if (top.getData().equals(trav.getData())) {
        count++;    
    }

    top = top.getNext();
}
```

You are changing the value of `top` and if you traverse the entire stack `top` will be null at the end of this function call.  Rewrite `equals()` so that it doesn't modify the state of your object.

You should also probably set `size = 0` in your `clear()` implementation and/or just override `isEmpty()` to check if `top==null` which would be a more robust check of emptiness (for instance I think you would then get a "stack is empty" instead of a null pointer here).

Comment: Boozah! I think you hit the nail on the head. It seems my equals() ain't working yet. If I take it off, it doesn't explode. Now, my equals is giving me a nullpointerexception on the if line...one problem solved, yet another arises.

Comment: I see.  I would still probably override isEmpty to just check if top is null.

Comment: I did, thanks. But now I'm getting a second null pointer exception for the trav.getData()...I'm so confused. Could it be that other is null?

Comment: I would strongly suggest stepping through the code with a debugger.  That way you can see exactly what the state of your variables is at each step of the method call.

Comment: Although my guess would be your `equals()` implementation doesn't work when the two lists are not the same size; possibly it tries to pull a matching element off of one side and gets null.

Comment: Oh man, thanks! That's actually the problem. I put a simple if on the equals to account for that, and it doesn't explode. Now, the size variable is adding two more times, 11, so its not equal to the other size's 9. Now I have to figure out why that is the case...but thanks!!

Comment: Nvm lol. It works perfectly now. Thanks so much FoolishSeth!!